# nodsj replacing encode decode method on request.post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, request

I am trying to send a post data to a website using nodejs request model.

im using the basic request.post method passing data as form data.

The issue is that the string i send is encoded with '%20'  instead of '+'
for the space char. how can i change it?

Comment: `%20` is for space only.

Comment: i tock this out from w3schools

Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.

URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.
URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

Comment: i just need to know how to control the encoding going out and i can't seem to find a way on the documentation itself of the request module

Comment: you can decode the string again using `decodeURI` .See this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI

Comment: thanks i tried something like that i also tried using utf8 library for nodejs my issue is when i send the request it encodes it again before sending

Comment: before it encodes again, you should decode it first. BTW were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: i didn't really managed to solve it. you can say i managed to bypass it by providing content-length headers manually the accepting server can handle the request now even %20 and not just +. 

ill update if i'll find out how to change the way the request model form encodes text.